# Python: Convert UTC time to localtime given UTC offset

Tags: python, datetime

Given the following Python datetime object representing an UTC time:

2016-09-15 22:13:03-2:00

I'm trying to obtain the corresponding local time datetime, where the UTC offset is applied:

2016-09-15 20:13:03

I was hoping to find a method in the datetime module that was able to do this, but I did not succeed. Any help is very appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Why would a UTC time be expressed with an adjustment? Beyond that, how is this object constructed? Is this really a `datetime.datetime` object, or just a string you need  to parse and convert?

Comment: using what python version?

Comment: I'm working with Python 2.7. It is a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best answer but here is what I have for you.  Typically I would not do this since it is better to use the UTC time and convert

Here is a example:

```
value = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(utc_datetime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
value = value.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
```

---

I was unable to use your datetime as the syntax is a bit off so I went ahead and used dateutil.parser to convert it to a datetime object

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> val = parse('2016-09-15 22:13:03-2:00')
```

There are other ways to set a datetime object to UTC but I find pytz to be the easiest

```
>>> import pytz
>>> utc_val = val.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Here is the output of those two values.  From here I grab the delta and subtract it

```
>>> val, utc_val
(datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 22, 13, 3, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -7200)), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 22, 13, 3, tzinfo=<UTC>))
>>>
>>> delta = val - utc_val
```

I remove the tzinfo since this is a converted datetime value

```
>>> local_dt = (val - delta).replace(tzinfo=None)
>>> local_dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 20, 13, 3)
>>> str(local_dt)
'2016-09-15 20:13:03'
```